# Enterprise Architect custom associations with the same stereotype

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I want to make a custom profile, in which there would be several custom associations. I want all of them to have the same stereotype and different default description. Currently when I define a second element with the same name (no matter whether in the same diagram or a different one), only the first one of them makes it into the final exported profile.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand the concept of UML Profiles.
A stereotype should be unique within a single profile, so you should never create two stereotypes with the same name in a profile.

Maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve in the first place we might be able to give you some useful advice.

Comment: I'currently drawing a lot of very similar connectors. All of them share a stereotype (which i use for visual filtering) and I make all of them thicker. I want to be have a connector with these properties already set in my toolbox. Additionally I would like to have two connectors of these common properties with a different description already set (in the toolbox).

Comment: So your question is rather, **Can I add the same stereotype with different default values in a toolbox?** right? Now that is a good question, but I'm afraid that is not possible.

Comment: Too bad. I guess an ugly workaround would be to define two separate profiles then.

Comment: Separate profiles with stereotypes that have the same name is a pretty sure way to mess up your model. EA is not particularly good ad distinguishing stereotypes with the same name from different profiles and you could end up with a big mess. Better alternative would be to write a little script to help the users set certain sets of default values (or provide different stereotypes after all)

Comment: If you mean clicking each time with a right mouse button and selecting a script that seems rather cumbersome. Is the element tied to the profile after it has been created? Removing the profile from the project altogether after creating its elements seems to work ok at first sight.